# Somehow my super admin username or password has updated by mistake in WSO2IS. How to reset it to admin and admin

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Somehow my super admin username or password has updated by mistake in WSO2IS. How to reset it to username=admin and password=admin. Now i can not login from my admin account.

Comment: That's not a programming question, so consider asking on e.g. superuser.com instead. Make sure to read their site guidelines first, though!

Comment: WSO2-IS Slack Channel (#Users channel) would be a better place for product-specific support. Find the link here https://github.com/wso2/is-community-call#links-to-bookmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the username and password using the **deployment.toml** file located in **<IS_HOME>/repository/conf** directory. You can find the below configuration there. Change this according to your need.

```
[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
```